# Generate a combination of possible words based on specific letter rule substitutions in Java

Tags: java, recursion

I'm having a little difficulty figuring the best way to go about about generating combinations for specific letters recursively.

Presently, I have a method which would changes a String and alters certains characters to create a single substitution of a word.

However, this isn't going to satisfy for the different combinations for the word. For example, if I have the word **kjng** commonly mistaken printer characters such as:

```
[j=>i, i=>j, v=>u, u=>v, s=>f, f=>s, uu=>w, vv=>w]  (map lookup, "=>" this is symbolic for key, value representation to make it extra clear)
```

Based on this method, the word would then become **king**. That's fine for a word with only one possibility. However along comes **murdir** which should generate the following:

```
  murdir
  mvrdjr
  mvrdir
  murdjr
```

A little advice on this would be great, presently I'm unsure of how best to go manage this scenario. For instance, how to keep track of the changes, do it in chunks of characters (*1, then 2, then 3, etc*).

Comment: I must admit I am not sure what exactly you want. Try to describe better the contract of your method - what is input, what *exactly* is the expected output.

Comment: Hi Honza, I thought I had made that assertion already above, i.e. the input of `murdir` would become a list of `murdir, mvrdjr, mvrdir, murdjr`. The substitution of letters being above also i.e. in a `map structure`.

Comment: Try to describe it generally, explicitly, not by example :)

Comment: Sorry Honza, I thought an example of a word would just be far more relatable

Comment: I intended to force you into realizing yourself what you want to do. Showing example is easier, but the general description navigates your brain towards the *algorithm* :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One changes a word at some position with some rule. And then recurses further. If the new word was already found stop for that case.

So basically you iterate of wordIndex and ruleIndex. Recursive formulation is easiest, and can later be changed to iterative. You could make two level of recursion: walk rules, walk inside word.

Okay, in java:

```
public class Solver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Solver");
        Solver solver = new Solver("j=>i", "i=>j", "v=>u", "u=>v", "s=>f",
            "f=>s", "uu=>w", "vv=>w");
        //Set<String> words = solver.determineAllWords("murdir");
        Set<String> words = solver.determineAllWords("gigi");
        words.forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.println("Done");
    }

    static class Rule {
        String from;
        String to;

        public Rule(String from, String to) {
            this.from = from;
            this.to = to;
        }
    }

    private final Rule[] rules;

    public Solver(String... tofroms) {
        this.rules = new Rule[tofroms.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < rules.length; ++i) {
            String[] tofrom = tofroms[i].split("=>", 2);
            rules[i] = new Rule(tofrom[0], tofrom[1]);
        }
    }

    public Set<String> determineAllWords(String word) {
        Set<String> solutionWords = new TreeSet<String>(); // Could be a field too.
        solutionWords.add(word);
        int ruleIndex = 0;
        int wordIndex = 0;
        solveTryingRules(solutionWords, word, wordIndex, ruleIndex);
        return solutionWords;
    }

    private void solveTryingRules(Set<String> solutionWords,
            String word, int wordIndex, int ruleIndex) {
        if (ruleIndex >= rules.length) {
            return;
        }
        Rule rule = rules[ruleIndex];
        int wordIndexFound = word.indexOf(rule.from, wordIndex);
        if (wordIndexFound == -1) {
            // Next rule:
            solveTryingRules(solutionWords, word, 0, ruleIndex + 1);
        } else {
                // Keep at same rule, 
            // Not applying rule to found word position:
            solveTryingRules(solutionWords, word, wordIndexFound + 1, ruleIndex);

            // Applying rule to found word position:
            String nextWord = word.substring(0, wordIndexFound)
                    + rule.to
                    + word.substring(wordIndexFound + rule.from.length());
            boolean added = solutionWords.add(nextWord);
            if (added) {
                solveTryingRules(solutionWords, nextWord, 0, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, I'm just wondering in the else why you call the solveTryingRules(...) again, but with the addition of adding one to the wordIndexFound ?

Comment: Admittedly the code is not so well-formulated as it should. I wanted to keep it short. the if-part jumps to the next rule. The else-part tries the current rule at this position (wordIndex) **or** tries another solution _without_ replacement at this position. The solution at this position recurses finally, with wordIndex and ruleIndex again 0.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is just tracking the changes and you want to be sure you generated **all** the combination but **none** of them **twice**, all you need is to find an **ordering** of the set of all the possible combinations.

I'd map your list of possible replacements to a sequence of bits, like this:

```
j=>i   ~ bit 0
i=>j   ~ bit 1
v=>u   ~ bit 2
u=>v   ~ bit 3
s=>f   ~ bit 4
f=>s   ~ bit 5
uu=>w  ~ bit 6
vv=>w  ~ bit 7

76543210
00101011 means you replace j=>i, i=>j, u=>v, f=>s
11000001 means you replace j=>i, uu=>w, vv=>w
```

Then implement some kind of binary counting (0, 1, 10, 11, 100, 101, 110, 111, 1000, 1001, 1010, 1011, 1100, ...) and generate the combinations based on the number.

I do not mean they have to be literally bits of a single long/integer variable, but the idea of ordering is this. Of course if you do not have more then 64 replacements then one single long variable is good:

```
String input = ...
List<...> replacements = ...
List<String> combinations = new ArrayList<>();
for (long count = 0; count < ...; count++) {
    String output = input;
    for (bit = 0; bit < 64; bit++) {
        if ((count & (1L << bit)) != 0) { // the bit is set
            // replace the characters based on replacements.get(bit)
            // output = ...
        }
    }
    combinations.add(output);
}
```

If you want to have it working for more unlimited number of replacements (> 64), you may use the same idea of ordering the set of all the combination and implement based on the ideas from [Variable Number of Nested For Loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18165937/variable-number-of-nested-for-loops).

Comment: Will this work if there is letter `i` in the text for example?

Comment: @kajacx: and why not?

Comment: Sorry, i meant to write "if `i` was in the text *twice*". Also strings are immutable in Java, so your `replace` have no change to change the `output` variable.

Comment: String immutable - yes, of course, you are right. It was just the very rough draft of the idea. I now removed this stupid thing, sorry for that. Letter `i` twice - the specification is not clear, if these are two different modifications or one.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do it recursively, how about this? This is python-like pseudocode.

```
#
# make a list of locations of all possible typos
# 

s = []     # list
for i in range(0, len(source)):
    if source[i] might be typo:
        s.append(i)

# 
# and to the recursion to find all combinations
#
print do_recurse(source, s)

# 
# method that returns the correct char corresponding to the typo
# 
def correction(char):
    # you should implement

# 
# the actual recursion method
#
def do_recurse(str, locations):
    '''
    return the list of all combinations
    '''
    if len(locations) <= 0:
        return []

    ret = []
    for loc in locations:
        # do the recursion with the string before the modification
        r = do_recurse(str, locations[1:])
        ret.extend( r )

        # do the recursion with the modified string
        str[loc] = correction(str[loc])
        r = do_recurse(str, locations[1:])
        ret.extend( r )

    return ret
```